# Whose voice was dubbed in for Flash Gordon?

Tags: movie, production, flash-gordon

In the 1980 film [*Flash Gordon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_%28film%29), the lead actor, Sam J. Jones playing Flash Gordon himself, departed from the project before post-production, leading to many of his lines being dubbed over by another actor. According to [this interview](http://www.maxim.com/entertainment/flash-gordon-speaks) with Jones (emphasis mine):

> I didn’t have a falling out with the director, but producer Dino De Laurentis and I bumped heads a few times - there were a few misunderstandings. In my naivety at the age of 25 I just let the attorneys handle everything - I just let my representation handle it and they did not do a very good job at all.  The bottom line, though, is they worked for me and I take responsibility for what happened. **I didn’t go back for looping and dubbing so they ended up using another actor to loop - I think about half the film was actually not my voice.**

So if it wasn't Jones's voice, whose was it?

### Whose voice was used in dubbing for the character of Flash Gordon?

<sub>This question was inspired by our *Flash Gordon* [movie night](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/movie-night-tuesday-the-22nd-nominate-your-favourite-terrible-sci-fi-fantasy-f) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).</sub>

Comment: Brian Blessed...the sod

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### TL;DR:  We don't know.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film)#Production) that the voice actor's identity is unknown, but cites the interview you quoted, which doesn't say anything about who that actor was or whether their identity is known:

> According to a 2012 interview in Maxim, Sam J. Jones had disagreements of some sort with De Laurentiis and departed prior to post-production, which resulted in a substantial proportion of his dialogue being dubbed by **a professional voice actor, whose identity is still a mystery**.

[Director Mike Hodges said](http://www.blastr.com/2010/08/director_reveals_the_real.php):

> I was very fond of Sam but here's what happened: we did the main shooting up until Christmas and then we stopped for the break. After Christmas I came back and did all of the second unit stuff too. For instance, I had to do the shots with the flying men and that sort of thing—what passed as special effects back then (laughs). So I also had to shoot a whole bunch of other stuff with a stunt double for Sam and **I had to re-voice the occasional line of dialogue too. Not much but some—and I got somebody to impersonate Sam's voice. You would never know it wasn't him.**
>
> But Sam found out and I think that was one factor that led to him being upset. And Dino and he just did not see eye to eye for a while. So when you lose your main star there can't really be a sequel.

[An article in Empire Magazine](http://www.mingocity.co.uk/samj_voice.htm) doesn't help much (emphasis mine):

> Director Mike Hodges keeps the pace cracking and shoots the whole piece from the crazy angles and in the lush colours of the original comic books. Queen's rock operatics deliver a score which is almost unique in being utterly inseparable from the success of the movie and Jones, now residing in DTV hell, deports himself admirably as the golden space boy - **even if 80 per cent of his lines are dubbed by *a still undisclosed voice***.

Nor does [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SameLanguageDub), which also confirms the fact that the voice actor is unidentified:

> On Flash Gordon, Sam J. Jones' voice was overdubbed by **an uncredited actor whose identity remains a mystery to this day** after Jones refused to return for post-production.

Answer (score 1):

After watching some clips, I firmly believe the voice belongs to Peter Marinker, a prolific dubbing voice actor at the time. Compare some of his other voice samples;

It's speculation, but am I crazy?